# Android java SELECT SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, methods

I created this query that takes data from 2 tables. But it seems that g.filed_1 is added and multiplied, because for example if the sum of g.filed_1 is 20, the query returns 40. Maybe there are syntax errors? Thanks

```
private void calc() {
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String tab = "SELECT SUM(c.field_init), SUM(g.filed_1), SUM(g.field_2) FROM Cserv c, Bserv g";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(tab, null);
if (c.moveToNext()) {
    sumfield_init = c.getDouble(0);
    sumfield_1 = c.getDouble(1);
    sumfield_2 = c.getDouble(2);
...
}
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify how to join the tables. The query therefore generates all possible combinations of the records in `Cserv` and `Bserv`. That you got twice the sum indicates that the other table just contains two records.

Typically, there would be one column in each table that should have the same value in the JOIN result. Assuming these columns are called `x` and `y`, you specify it in this way:

```
SELECT SUM(c.field_init), SUM(g.filed_1), SUM(g.field_2) FROM Cserv c JOIN Bserv g
    ON c.x = g.y
```

Comment: the problem is that the tables do not have an equal field. then the union of the fields can not be applied.

Comment: Whats the point of the JOIN then? Can't you calculate the sums for each table individually?

Comment: I entered the JOIN to try, but I always got double the value of the field `g.filed_1`. 
At this point I could do 2 separate queries, but then what should I do with the `cursor`?

Answer (score 0):

```
specify the column names as i did below     

private void calc() {
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String tab = "SELECT SUM(c.field_init), SUM(g.filed_1), SUM(g.field_2) 
FROM Cserv c.KEY FROM THIS TABLE JOIN    Bserv g.KEY FROM Bserv";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(tab, null);
if (c.moveToNext()) {
sumfield_init = c.getDouble(0);
sumfield_1 = c.getDouble(1);
sumfield_2 = c.getDouble(2);
...
}
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea? I can not enter the JOIN. do not have an equal field.

Answer (score 0):

> **the problem is that the tables do not have an equal field. then the union of the fields can not be applied. *- user3160725***

If you want the individual sums in one query, you can unite the separate queries into one **without** performing a `JOIN` between the two tables. There are many ways to do this, and you can choose whatever makes most sense to you:

The individual sums are as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(c.field_init) FROM Cserv c; --x
SELECT SUM(g.filed_1) FROM Bserv g; --y
SELECT SUM(g.field_2) FROM Bserv g; --z
```

**Method 1.** You can unite them as subqueries in a main query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(c.field_init) FROM Cserv c),
  (SELECT SUM(g.filed_1) FROM Bserv g),
  (SELECT SUM(g.field_2) FROM Bserv g);
```

Here, you are getting each sum in a subquery as a column in the main query. Note that each subquery must have exactly one column and one row.

```
   x     y     z
```

**Method 2.** You can unite them by aggregating:

```
SELECT SUM(sum1), SUM(sum2), SUM(sum3) FROM (
  (SELECT SUM(c.field_init) AS sum1, 0 AS sum2, 0 AS sum3 FROM Cserv c)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 0, SUM(g.filed_1), SUM(g.field_2) FROM Bserv g)
);
```

Here, you are getting this table in the subquery:

```
sum1  sum2  sum3
   x     0     0
   0     y     z
```

And totalling the sums in the main query:

```
sum1  sum2  sum3
   x     y     z
```

**Method 3.** You can perform a union:

```
SELECT SUM(c.field_init) FROM Cserv c
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(g.filed_1) FROM Bserv g
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(g.field_2) FROM Bserv g;
```

In this case the sums will be in separate rows, but on a single column. You will have to modify your program logic to read each rows separately and assign them properly.

```
   x
   y
   z
```

Method 3 can only work if the order of rows is guaranteed. For guarantee, you may do the following instead:

```
SELECT 1, SUM(c.field_init) FROM Cserv c
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, SUM(g.filed_1) FROM Bserv g
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, SUM(g.field_2) FROM Bserv g;
```

Resulting in:

```
   1     x
   2     y
   3     z
```

You can then be sure than when first column is `2`, the second column carries the sum of `g.filed_1`, and so on.